# How to use POST value in else part?

Tags: php

In below code `$username` is the variable which i required in `else` part too. how can i get it? Please help me. As i m new to PHP. I dont know if it is correct or not but please help me in that.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    require_once('dbConnect.php');
    $sql = "select * from login where username='$username'";

    $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql));

    if(isset($check))
    {
        echo "success";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Invalid Username ";
    }

}
else
{
    //here i want to use $username
}
```

Comment: 1. initialize `$username` above the `if` | 2. When you are assigning username inside if, what you expect inside `else`?

Comment: @Thamilan but i m getting $username from post method

Comment: You have to post more details about your question i mean what you want to do.

Comment: @PankajMahadik then what do you expect inside else?

Comment: What should `$username` contain if the user hasn't posted the form?

Comment: @Barmar still i want that value in $username even if it is not posted the form... is there any way?

Comment: What do you mean by "that value"? If the form isn't posted, there's no value.

Comment: Maybe you need to use a session variable so you can use the value from a previous posting?

Comment: to be very frank i want this in android app, where when i logged into account it should fetch data from mysql database according to username.

Answer (score 0):

change from

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
  {
     $username = $_POST['username'];
     require_once('dbConnect.php');
     $sql = "select * from login where username='$username'";

     $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql));

    if(isset($check))
    {
        echo "success";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Invalid Username ";
    }

}
    else
      {
     //here i want to use $username
      }
```

to

```
$username = (isset($_POST['username']))?$_POST['username']:'';
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
  {
     require_once('dbConnect.php');
     $sql = "select * from login where username='".$username."'";

     $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql));

    if(isset($check))
    {
        echo "success";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Invalid Username ";
    }

}
    else
      {
     //here i want to use $username
       echo $username;
      }
```

Comment: thnk u @dhruv jadia